# summernote (data not saving in DB) (laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, summernote

I am using laravel 5.2 and integrating summernote js in the site.

I want that when user fills the form and click on save ,all the data get stored in Database.

It worked for a single field but not for two or more.

my view:

```
    <form action="{{route('account')}}" id="acc" class="ac" method="post">
  <div class="col-lg-3"><label>Estado</label>

  @foreach($accounts as $account)
  @if($user== $account->user)
  {!! $account->estado !!}
  <textarea  style="display:none;" name="textfield4" id="textfield4"></textarea></div>

  <div class="col-lg-2 es" id="estado"></div>


 <a span class="fa fa-heartbeat"  id="sex" aria-hidden="true">
    </span></a>
</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <section class="col-lg-3"><div><br><label for="textfield5">I'm Good At:</label>


   <p>{!! $account->goodat !!}</p>


   <textarea  style="display:none;" name="textfield5" id="textfield5"></textarea></div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 es" id="goodat"></div>
   @endif
  @endforeach
```

my JS in view:

```
 <script>

var edit = function() {
  $('#estado').summernote({focus: true});
   $('#goodat').summernote({focus: true});
};

var save = function() {
  var makrup = $('#estado').summernote('code');
  $('#estado').summernote('destroy');

  var makrup = $('#goodat').summernote('code');
  $('#goodat').summernote('destroy');
};

$(".acc").submit(function(e) {
     var self = this;
     e.preventDefault();


    //$('#estado').summernote('destroy');
     var estado = $('#estado').summernote('code');
     $("#textfield4").html(estado); //populate text area



      var goodat = $('#goodat').summernote('code');
     $("#textfield5").html(goodat); //populate text area
     self.submit();
     return false; 


});



</script>
```

my controller:

```
 se App\Account;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class AccountController extends Controller
{

 public function account(Request $request)
    {

        $account = new Account();
        $account->estado = $request->input('textfield4');
        $account->goodat = $request->input('textfield5');
        $request->user()->accounts()->save($account);


        return redirect()->route('myplace',['username'=>Auth::user()->username]);
    }



}
```

Comment: the dd($request) is a good first step, however you should show the content of attributes and request within your Request dump. You can also try to dd($request->input()) for clearer result

Comment: a first wild guess is that you should not set the textarea content using .html() but using .val()

Comment: @FrankProvost on doing dd($request->input()) i am getting this: 

array:4 [▼
  "textfield4" => ""
  "textfield5" => ""
  "textfield9" => ""
  "_token" => "HBJGDY760fxF6v5b2eJSOA2G0f2D0saMp3KtTZRg"
]

Comment: also .val() didnt worked.

Comment: As you can see you are actually sending empty strings - therefore your problem is in the frontend. If you are using chrome press f12 to open the developer tools. go to console and enter $('#estado').summernote('code'); - ensure this returns your wanted input

Comment: VM787:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'summernote' of null(…)........i did '$('#estado').summernote('code')' after clicking save button.

Comment: Do you have an element with the id estado?

Comment: yes, <div class="col-lg-2 es" id="estado"></div>

Comment: try to find the root of the problem. First step would be to manage that $('#estado') does not reutrn null anymore. Run your scripts within a document.ready function and try again. Use the console for quick tests

Comment: sorry didnt get you, pls tell me how to do it.

Comment: - no problem - maybe add the where you load jquery and the other scripts to your question. What is the response when calling $('#estado') from your console directly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122478/discussion-between-yash-chaudhary-and-frank-provost).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122478 the actual problem was missing

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... });
```

and

```
$(".acc").submit(function(e) { ... });
```

The actual class of the form was .ac not .acc - however the id is acc

Also the edit has to be changed since it could not be called from onclick event direktly when wrapped in the ready function.

In the discussion you can find the markup of the page - pasting this in a full blown IDE will show tons of errors - therefore I'll provide a few more tips regarding the state of the code.

- You have many many many duplicate id's. Do not set id's to objects that do not need to be identified by an id - there's no need to. If you have a loop you cannot simply say id="example" - each time you loop through it will create an entity with the same id. jQuery will not be able to identify them. If you want to get them all use classes - if you want to identify them directly use an incrementor in your loop
- Missuse of Markup: You have divs in `<ul>` tags which should not be done.
- `</br>` is wrong either use `<br>` or `<br/>`
- a lot of not closing tags label B'day: label ( two times opening)
- form action="http://localhost:8000/account" id="acc" class="ac" method="post" is not closing - there is no `</form>` for this - do not forget to call Form::close()

Try to get a proper editor that helps you with this stuff. I'm using intellij webstorm which actually costs a little bit (is free for students).

Answer (score -3):

Have you validated that the request input is present in the function?

Maybe you could check with a:

```
dd($request);
```

Comment: I've included the screenshot in the question

Comment: This is not a full answer, this should be a comment